# How can my application access the keystore configured in Weblogic admin console?

Tags: weblogic, keystore

I would like to access the Identity keystores (JKS) configured in Weblogic's Custom keystore configuration in my web application. How can I get weblogic to expose this without relying on the following environment properties: -Djavax.net.ssl.Keystore, -Djavax.net.ssl.KeystorePassword.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code as a starting point.

A couple of notes:

- User executing the code needs to belong to a group called `OracleSystemGroup`
- Keystore is loaded from file system which is not recommended by EJB specification. But I think that file reading can be safely done.
- Keystore passphrase is contained in `java.lang.String`, which is not recommended.

Because of these cons I am investigating a better approach. I have been trying to find a WebLogic service which would provide services to access certificates and keys in identity store. It seems that [there is not one](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13710/archtect.htm#i1062666).

```java
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
MBeanServer server = (MBeanServer) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/runtime");

// Get access to server configuration
ObjectName runtime = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=RuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime.RuntimeServiceMBean");
ObjectName serverConfig = (ObjectName) server.getAttribute(runtime, "ServerConfiguration");

/* Load identity store location and passphrase.
 * If e.g. Demo identity has been configured (in WL console) instead of
 * custom identity then the following does not work.
 */

// Passphrase as clear text
Object keyStorePassPhrase = server.getAttribute(serverConfig, "CustomIdentityKeyStorePassPhrase");
Object keyStoreFileName = server.getAttribute(serverConfig, "CustomIdentityKeyStoreFileName");

// Load keystore
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(new FileInputStream(keyStoreFileName.toString()),
        keyStorePassPhrase.toCharArray());
```