# Is it applicable to get java key store (jks) that exited in webloigc in java code?

Tags: java, weblogic, jks

I want to access java key store from weblogic in java code .i tried solution like i get `JMXConnector` and get jks path but it gives me null. I tired to access local path in local hard disk it gives me certifications. But I don't know should I get the path from weblogic or get resource or should I get by specific path from local.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String serverName = "AdminServer";
    String hostName = "127.0.0.1";
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    int port = 7001;
    String protocol = "t3";
    String jndiroot = "/jndi/";
    String mserver = "weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime";
    JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(protocol, hostName, port, jndiroot + mserver);
    Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
    h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
    h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    h.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "weblogic.management.remote");
    JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h);
    ObjectName objName = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=" + serverName + ",Type=Server");
    String pathJKS = (String) connector.getMBeanServerConnection().getAttribute(objName, "CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName");
    System.out.println(pathJKS);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can my application access the keystore configured in Weblogic admin console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399167/how-can-my-application-access-the-keystore-configured-in-weblogic-admin-console)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial  .this is the output of code in link